# Allowing the zero element in a field to have an inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In the definition of a field one of the required properties is that

***every element other than zero has a multiplicative inverse***.

It's vague whether the zero is forced not to have an inverse or not, as in is the property

***every element other than zero has a multiplicative inverse and zero does not***

or

***every element other than zero has a multiplicative inverse and zero may or may not***?

Regardless, what differences would occur if we adopted one definition as opposed to the other?

Comment: To whomever, the down vote seems unnecessary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you kept all of the other usual axioms, then

$$ 0 = 0 \cdot 0^{-1} = 1 $$

$$ x = x \cdot 1 = x \cdot 0 = 0 $$

and so all numbers are zero. This is rather degenerate. This is called the "zero ring"; usually we do not consider this ring to be a field.

Comment: Why does $aa^{-1} = 0$ hold?

Comment: @Jossie: because everything is zero.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that $0$ has no inverse in a ring (with identity $1\ne0$) is a result of the distributive property of multiplication and mentioning it in a definition is redundant:

$$\quad ab=(0+a)b=0b+ab \implies 0b=ab-ab=0$$

Answer (score 1):

If $0$ had a multiplicative inverse, then $0=0*0^{-1}=1$, so your ring would be the trivial one. By the way, this holds for any ring, not just for fields.

Answer (score 1):

If in a ring $R$ the zero $0$ has an inverse, then $R=0$ (in fact, $1 = 0 \cdot 0^{-1} = 0$, hence $r = 1r = 0r = 0$ for all $r \in R$). One wants fields to be non-zero for many reasons, for example for the uniquenes of the dimension (remark that $R^n \cong R^m$ for all $n,m$ when $R=0$). Therefore the second definition is correct (i.e. coincides with the usual definition of a field), whereas the first and the third also include the zero ring, which is not a field.

Comment: Why $R^n\cong R^m$ gives a problem with uniqueness of dimension? Wouldn't we have $dim R^n=dim R^m =0$, $=$ also to $n\times0=m\times 0=0$?